# How can I get email to "me" to email to my email address?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

If I tell Siri "email me," the right thing happens: a new message is created with my email address as the recipient. But if I open the email app and type "me" as the recipient, I'm told "Invalid Address" when I try to send the message.

How can I get the email app to understand that "me" as a recipient means to use the email address corresponding to who I've told Siri is me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't.

Because of the design of iOS, there is no native way to accomplish this. The reason for this is that the address field in mail and messages are almost exactly identical, not just in looks, but in function.

In messages, you can actually send a text to `me`, but it will send whatever you said straight to `63` (see number pad). This is because some companies hand out shortcodes, and say something like *Text APP to WMART (96278) to download the Walmart app!*. users can *either* punch in 96278 into messages, *or* they can punch in the much more memorable WMART into the address field and still have the message go back to the right place.

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that mail will actually try to send an email to `me` if you hit send. This *may* be a planned feature for within organizations or something, or it could be an oversight. But **due to the design of iOS, you are unable to accomplish what you wanted.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to put on your full email address in the "to" address bar
the above answer is Right in some point.The Application will try to send the mail to me,if you really want to send by typing me then you should try saving your own mail address with the name of mee and then you can try(not confirmed but i am 90% sure it will work)
and siri will send to ur mailbox cause u have saved your email address in there so it will automatically redirect there.
So you need to save your own mail address n u can try or can write down the full mail address